# Why i am getting output in a single line?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

File name :
BufferedReaderExample.txt

```
hello
amarnath
durga
india
asia
```

source file : BufferedReaderExample.java

```
import java.io.*;
class  BufferedReaderExample
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("BufferedReaderExample.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String s = br.readLine();
    while(s!=null)
    {
        System.out.print(s);
        s = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close(); 
}
}
```

Why i am getting output in a single line ?

```
helloamarnathdurgaindiaasia
```

Comment: you are reading as **line**, then print without newline

Comment: because you're using `System.out.print` and not `System.out.println`

Comment: you are using print, which is print it without line break.... try to do some more research before asking

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this to add a new line:

`System.out.print(s + “\n”)`

or maybe if you want to have a space between each word then:

`System.out.print(s + “ ”)`

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
System.out.print(s);
```

If you want each line to be separated, please use this instead:

```
System.out.println(s);
```